# Understanding prototype method calls

Tags: javascript

In trying to call a method on the [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/manual.html) javascript code editor.  I'm new to javascript and trying to understand how object oriented stuff works.  I'm having problems calling what I believe are methods.  For instance,

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea('code', options);
editor.grabKeys(function(e) { alert("Key event");});
```

This gives the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'grabKeys' of undefined`.  Looking at the `editor` object reveals that grabKeys seems to be located at `editor.__proto__.grabKeys`.

How should I be thinking about this?

Comment: Looks like `CodeMirror.fromTextArea('code', options);` returns `undefined`. Maybe you are passing the wrong arguments to that function?

Comment: If I console.log(editor) it returns as an object I can explore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably yoour code should be something like this:

```
var editor = new CodeMirror.fromTextArea('code', options);
editor.grabKeys(function(e) { alert("Key event");});
```

Notice the 'new' operator..

Here is a good explanation of what prototype method calls are for:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto.shtml

Comment: The linked-to documentation suggests otherwise.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that fromTextArea is a utility function that constructs the object for you.  So what is your 'options' object?

Can you post the contents here?

Comment: They're the default and work. For instance, adding the editor.grabKeys function to this example: http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/contrib/python/index.html

Comment: Very strange.  If I add `editor.grabKeys(function(e) { alert("Asdf");})` in the javascript console it works.  If I add it in the html file, right after the editor, it doesn't.  Ideas?

Comment: Seems this call is async.  Need to use `initCallback:`.