# "prototype" in jQuery fn? + plain javascript code inside a jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

i was wondering what prototype means in jQuery? i usually find infos about "Prototype" - the framework - but here it's "prototype" inside jQuery...? Could you please tell me when it's best to use it?

Also, could you tell me : why do we use a "plain javascript" code inside a jQuery plugin, instead of the jquery code, like in this example? is it a rapidity issue?

here's my example : (a plugin for twitter)

Thanks for your answers !

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {  
    holder.append("<p>"+item.text.makeLinks()+"</p>");  
});  
//...further in the code  
String.prototype.makeLinks = function() {  
    return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/,   function(str) {  
        return str.link(str);  
    });  
};
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> I was wondering what "prototype" means in jQuery

The JavaScript library named Prototype takes its name from the [JavaScript prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Prototype-based). In JavaScript, the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) is the mechanism which provides inheritance (as opposed to, say, classes). Example:`String.prototype` refers to the `prototype` object of `String`s, which contains (among other things) methods which can be invoked on any `String`.

In the example in your question, the twitter plugin creates a new function on `String.prototype`, called `makeLinks`, which allows for function calls such as:

```
text.makeLinks()
```

where `text` is a string.

More reading on prototypes:

- [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)
- [How are prototype functions different than normal functions in javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871349/prototype-in-javascript)
- [Understanding prototype method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962536/understanding-prototype-method-calls)
- [Understanding JavaScript prototypes](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/)

---

> Why do we use a "plain javascript" code inside a jQuery plugin, instead of the jQuery code?

jQuery is not a replacement for JavaScript. It is a JavaScript library, meant to make it easier to write JavaScript *which would otherwise have to use the DOM API.* You see "vanilla" JavaScript in the jQuery plugin because there's really no better way to do what that JS does.

**jQuery is JavaScript.** It simplifies writing other JavaScript by providing a simpler API which remains consistent across browsers. This is not the case with the DOM, because the various browser vendors have created DOM APIs which are *mostly* the same, but not identical.

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is a site popular for documenting these inconsistencies (in CSS as well as in JavaScript).

---

Welcome to web development!

Answer (score 11):

Prototype is a pure javascript functionality.

It's used to add properties or methods to an already defined object (somewhat like extending). For example:

```
function myCustomObject(){
}

myCustomObject.prototype.myCustomAttr = "Hello";

var instance = new myCustomObject();

alert(instance.myCustomAttr); // alerts Hello
```